# How to add content HTTP_HOST variable to query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

i need to create a rewrite rule/condition that always rewrites the http_host to the query string.

i have multiple domains and all of them point to the same DocumentRoot.
What i want to do now is, to add the called domain-name (e.g.) example1.org to the query-string for application internal use. Let's say the application is situated at baseapplication.org

opening

```
example.org
```

in my browser runs into document root and htaccess should rewrite it internally to:

```
baseapplication.org?requested_domain=example1.org
```

i cannot find a combination of rewrite rules or conditions to get that running.

Comment: Instead of finding "combinations" and "copy-paste recipes" you could just read documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I'm not actually sure you can internally rewrite to a different host (without it sending a Location header).  Can anyone confirm/deny this?

Comment: You would either have to redirect to the new domain or you can have apache map multiple domains to the same document root (or different root) and use php to access which site is being requested.

Answer (score 1):

Im not a .HTACCESS pro, but this should do the trick.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

have that in your root, in a file named .HTACCESS along with a index.php file.
Then in the index file you can access all the request vars.

From here you can either do a [php headers redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), or include the file from another dir.
up to you.

Not a solution, but should help a little

Answer (score 0):

From the Apache documentation:

#### Description:

Assume that you want to provide www.username.host.domain.com for the homepage of username via just DNS A records to the same machine and without any virtualhosts on this machine.

#### Solution:

For HTTP/1.0 requests there is no solution, but for HTTP/1.1 requests which contain a Host: HTTP header we can use the following ruleset to rewrite http://www.username.host.com/anypath internally to /home/username/anypath:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^www\.[^.]+\.host\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^www\.([^.]+)\.host\.com(.*) /home/$1$2
```

There are a handful of other HTTP rewrites at the [Apache Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).